# Tesseract OCR ignores the lines contain the asterisk

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I have the image created from old fax document (the font is specific) Generally Tesseract works pretty ok with this input, except one use case. When the line starts with many leading asterisk '*' than it is ignored.

The result produces by ocr is different for given psm
[image: the fax with *]

1. **psm 1**: the empty page
2. **psm 6**: `For queries please contact NA, KRKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK KKK KK KK KK`

In every use case the tittle "comment" is skipped

But when I manually in Paint removed the all '*' from image[image: image without *] then the ocr works fine.  I ve no idea how to process the ocr without image preprocessing. Can someone understand it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `tesseract 9UIKs.png - --psm 4 --oem 0`

Which produces:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxkkkk COMMENT kkkkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

For queries p1ease contact NA.

XXXXXKKKKXXXVXKKKKKXXXXXKXXXXXXXXXXXXKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXKKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXKXXXX.
```

You will need language model with support for legacy engine (from here https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata)

Comment: Yeap It's working. But I don't want to change the language model ( my current one does not support the legacy oem:0 - the change is too huge and too risky.   Is there any option to fix the output without touching the oem ???

Still I don't understand why tesseract got lost in this case